# QTextEdit print rightToLeft arabic text

Tags: qt, printing, right-to-left, qtextedit

i have problem with QtextEdit::drawContents() 
whene i print right to left arabic char with other char like "-" or ":"
the output is reversed 
in other words whene i try printing  **:ببببب -**    the result is **-ببببب :**